# the logt abbreviation not work in AndroidStudio live templates

Tags: android, android-studio, live-templates

The logt abbreviation not work, but logd or logm works, in AndroidStudio live templates.
When input logt, it generates **private static final String TAG = "Cannot invoke method length() on null object";**, and its expression is "groovyScript("_1.take(Math.min(23, _1.length()));", className())". It seems noting is wrong, but the logt result is wrong.

Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3
macOS 11.4

Answer (score 0):

Like me, it seems to be caused by className() in groovy,

This is my temporary solution:

**Replace with fileNameWithoutExtension().**

Here:

```
groovyScript("_1.take(Math.min(23, _1.length()));", fileNameWithoutExtension())
```

Comment: Yes, this is also my  temporary solution, but it's not work in inner class.

Comment: @AnswerZhao try `groovyScript("def name=_1.substring(_1.lastIndexOf('.')+1);name.take(Math.min(23, name.length()));", qualifiedClassName())`

Comment: @wangqi060934 nice